# Возможно ли в Java рисовать диагональные линии с ровными краями?

Tags: java, графика, awt

Возможно ли в Java рисовать диагональные линии, да и другие фигуры, с ровными краями? То есть, по сути векторные линии. 
На изображении видно что диагональные линии идут, как бы лесенкой, а необходимо,чтобы они были "гладкими". Можно ли в Java рисовать именно ровные (гладкие, векторные) линии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Какие технологии/библиотеки/фреймворки вы используете, какой вывод, где используется и так далее.

Comment: Использую библиотеку awt. Пишу простое графическое приложение. Линию вывожу через gr.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2); Линию вывожу в JPanel, которая в свою очередь находится в JFrame.